# merge the matrix from computematrix of deeptools

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, chip-seq, deeptools

I have several matrix from computematrix of deeptools. I need to merge two of them using "computeMatrixOperations cbind -m input1.mat.gz input2.mat.gz -o output.mat.gz"
but I am running to error "/computeMatrixOperations.py", line 521, in cbindMatrices
    hm.matrix.matrix = np.hstack((hm.matrix.matrix, np.empty(hm2.matrix.matrix.shape)))"

Is there any other way to merge the matrixes?

Comment: Please post the full error message, not just a single line.

Comment: Thanks, here is the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zudmn4lwo3yikw6/Capture.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cbind two matrices of different sizes, so computeMatrix is throwing an error since it's unclear which row goes with which. You need to ensure that matrices have exactly the same number of rows and that the Nth row in each match (i.e., they should be bound together with cbind).